# Do I have to set the height of the container?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:760px;    

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;

    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;  
}

#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    background:red;
}

#wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:460px;
background:blue;
```

}

and this HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Example.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="sidebar">
                        LEFT
            </div>

            <div id="wrapper">
                RIGHT
            </div>          
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I see that the container has no height.... do I Must set it? I would like to explain the height depending on the height of the inner DIVs, How could i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to set the height, just add:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

directly below any divs that you float.

---

In your case, you could do this:

Just add this to your CSS file.

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

And update your HTML file to match

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Example.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="sidebar">
                        LEFT
            </div>

            <div id="wrapper">
                RIGHT
            </div>    
            <div class="clear"></div>      
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you! if i don't use it, it does not follow the height of the inner DIVs because it can't understand if there are other elements at the ends?

Comment: @Dail floated elements are removed from the document flow, and thus do not affect 'height' of their parents.  `clear:both` tells the div to resume normal document flow here, and allows it to recognize the height

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you used `float:left`. One solution is to add a `clear:both` div as follow:

CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">LEFT</div>
    <div id="wrapper">RIGHT</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the container the additional CSS

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will break the float with no extra markup
(Will not work with box-shadow inside)